# Importing a function from a file from two directories up

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

Here is what my project looks like

```
Folder1/
    Examples/
        JupyterNotebook.ipynb

    Module1/
        __init__.py
        file1.py

    __init__.py
    file2.py
```

I am in JupyterNotebook.ipynb. I want to do two things:

- Import a function `function2` from `file2.py`.
- Import a class `class1` in `file1.py` inside the `Module1`.

How can I do that?

I tried something like

```
from ...Folder1.file2 import function2
```

or

```
from ...Folder1.Module1.file1 import foo
```

but I get

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sys.path.append` to import modules beyond top level ones:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")

from file2 import function2
from Module1.file1 import class1 

my_class = class1()
function2()
```

Comment: This doesn't work but `sys.path.append("..")` works for me!

Comment: Dunno, maybe OS difference.

Answer (score -2):

Your dot notation is not correct. Use the following instead:

```
from Folder1.file2 import function2
from Folder1.Module1.file1 import class1
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Folder1'`. Did you try it yourself?

Comment: Of course, I tried it before sending. And it worked in my environment.

Comment: From the jupyternotebook file.

Comment: Blame the os difference.